# Align Checkbox to center of the ListView item

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-checkbox

The following layout is used in my app to show cliplists.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ClipNo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clip No"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ClipTime"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ClipDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/ClipMark"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**The below image shows the output of the layout**

[image]

**How can i arrange the 'CheckBox' to center of the 'Mark'  Header**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because you have added `android:layout_weight="1"`

Change your below code

```
 <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/ClipMark"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

To

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <CheckBox 
            android:id="@+id/ClipMark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The important part is the layout_width to be set to "wrap_content" and the parent's gravity to be "center". You can use whatever parent layout you'd like. It also works perfectly well inside a table row for example.

Answer (score 3):

I placed the `CheckBox` inside a `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ClipNo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clip No"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ClipTime"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ClipDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/ClipMark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a **`LinearLayout`** as **PARENT**.

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/ClipMark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the device Layout Boundaries, the `CheckBox` is rightly aligned to center as per your current layout. Add the `CheckBox` to a layout(`LinearLayout` example) and implement the layout.
 It should work.
 **TIP**: Refer: [CheckBox official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this add your `CheckBox` inside a `RelativeLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ClipNo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Clip No"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ClipTime"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Time"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ClipDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/ClipMark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one it had worked for me

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/interested_item_checkbox"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            style="@style/interested_item_textview"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ich just put a negative Margin-Value to my Checkbox

```
<style name="details_checkbox">
    <item name="android:scaleX">0.80</item>
    <item name="android:scaleY">0.80</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentEnd">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">-4dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you replay to a question, please describe it, even if it is right. In your case, there are a few more answers so show the Pros and Cons of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Replace checkbox xml code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ClipMark"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Above solutions work, only for equal widths (weight=1). When you have different weights, one needs to add a margin value to center the checkbox correctly.

For instance, add ​a positive Margin-Value to the Checkbox

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:gravity="center">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/secondary_axis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```