# Why don't work Gravity center for Check Box

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, checkbox

I have a checkBox and set gravity center but the box doesn't come center

this is my XML file

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:checked="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    app:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:scaleX="1.4"
    android:scaleY="1.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

CheckBox image:

[image: CheckBox image here]

Comment: What type of Layout used?

Comment: @liangZhenbo I used constraint layout

Comment: Did you find any answeres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself solved this problem with style

first set the style attribute

```
android:theme="@style/checkBoxStyle"
```

Create a style

```
<style name="checkBoxStyle" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

ConstraintLayout Chains
Android developers recently released a new version of ConstraintLayout (1.0.2 as of today). This version contains a new major feature - Chains, which allows us to group views in ConstraintLayout.

Chains provide group-like behavior in a single axis (horizontally or vertically).

A set of widgets are considered a chain if they a linked together via a bi-directional connection

Once a chain is created, there are two possibilities:

Spread the elements in the available space
A chain can also be "packed", in that case the elements are grouped together

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm mistaken, but I tried the same with radio buttons and it only centered the text associated with the radiobutton. But I think you might find your answer over here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47386980/align-checkbox-to-center-of-the-listview-item/47387075#:~:text=Create%20a%20LinearLayout%20as%20PARENT.&text=If%20you%20check%20the%20device,It%20should%20work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47386980/align-checkbox-to-center-of-the-listview-item/47387075#:%7E:text=Create%20a%20LinearLayout%20as%20PARENT.&text=If%20you%20check%20the%20device,It%20should%20work).

Comment: You have a constraint layout. Inside it you need to make a linear layout in which you will place the checkbox.